# create new column in pandas dataframe based on criteria on different other columns

Tags: pandas

I want to create a new column in pandas based on criteria on some other columns. Usually this can be done using np.select but I am wondering if it can be done differently. For example create a tag columnn with 'yes' based on values in cols I1=1,I2=2 and I3=3 else 'no'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": [ "N1", "N2", "N3" ],
    "I1": [ 1, 4, 4 ],
    "I2": [ 2, 5, 2 ],
    "I3": [ 3, 6, 6 ]
})

df
Out[76]: 
  NAME  I1  I2  I3
0   N1   1   2   3
1   N2   4   5   6
2   N3   4   2   6

df['tag']=['yes' if ((x==1) & (y==2) & (z==3)) else 'no' for x,y,z in df['I1'],df['I2'],df['I2']]
  File "<ipython-input-77-3bbe8c32a03c>", line 1
    df['tag']=['yes' if ((x==1) & (y==2) & (z==3)) else 'no' for x,y,z in df['I1'],df['I2'],df['I2']]
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use `np.select`?

Comment: Good question. I am just trying to be a bit consistent with the codes. np.select would perhaps be the fastest but I am keen to know how it can be done this way as well.

Comment: OK, then everything looks fine just make sure you `zip` your frames: `df['tag'] = ['yes' if ((x==1) & (y==2) & (z==3)) else 'no' for x,y,z in zip(df['I1'], df['I2'], df['I3'])]`

Answer (score 1):

I will do condition in `dict` then use `eq` with `all`

```
cond_d = {'I1':1,'I2':2,'I3':3}
df.iloc[:,1:].eq(cond_d ).all(1).map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
Out[218]: 
0    Yes
1     No
2     No
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": [ "N1", "N2", "N3" ],
    "I1": [ 1, 4, 4 ],
    "I2": [ 2, 5, 2 ],
    "I3": [ 3, 6, 6 ]
})


df['tag'] = np.where((df['I1'] == 1) | (df['I2'] == 2) | (df['I3'] == 3), 'yes', 'no')
```